# How to not delete untracked files from git when pulling

Tags: git, github

My friend and I are working on a git repository. Actually i made a mistake by setting all files on stage before adding .gitignore file, and i pushed all on github, my friend have clonned the project as well.

Now to solve the problem, i have manually untracked those files with `git rm --cached <files>` , and i did a seconde push, to get those files removed from github.

But the problem here is when my friend try to get my last update on github, the `pull` command deletes all those files that i have untracked from his local repository.

Is there a way to tell git to not delete those files that i have untracked, when my friend try to `pull` the latest version of the project ?

The only solution that i have in mind for now, is to tell my friend to manually untrack those files, just like i did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have them mixed-reset to your commit:

```
git fetch origin
git reset origin/master
```

This will update their branch to reflect your removal commit, but not change the files in the working directory.